# Change to another view from a custom button

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Just started with a nice little tutorial for Xcode and iphone dev. I have created a simple single view project .I have added the code for the custom button in ViewDidLoad (ViewController.m)which*the button) is pointing at showAboutPage function with

```
[aboutBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(showAboutPage) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside)];
```

My button is showing correctly and have all the necessary code for highlight,color,font.

What code should i implement inside

```
- (void) showAboutPage
{

}
```

in order to push into the second view(redView.xib).
Playing around with storyboard is easy,i can do it with "connecting the lines"/drag n drop,but programmatically is what i want so i can learn the correct way.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should make it clear whether you want a view or view controller. Push maybe is better for view controller and redView.xib is a better name for view not a view controller.

Comment: I think your answer later in this thread should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Your view's first letter should uppercase, redView=>RedView. Another suggest is that I think use IBAction is better than add target to a button. After you have added the RedView.h, RedView.m and RedView.xib you should set RedView.xib's class to RedView in Interface Builder. Then you can use it like this:

```
- (void) showAboutPage
{
    RedView *redView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RedView" owner:self options:nil]] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.view addSubview:redView];
}
```

Comment: I am getting these errors : Expected identifier
Unexpected interface name 'RedView': expected expression.Dont know where is the problem.

Comment: I mean you should refactor your class from redView to RedView(right click the variable redView, choose Refactor->rename), then try the code I've written.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're doing all this in the view controller class (that's what I deduced from your description):

```
- (void)showAboutPage
{
    AboutPageViewController *about = [[AboutPageViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:about animated:YES];
    // If you're not using ARC:
    [about release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i ll check and get back with results.

Comment: He want to add a view not a view controller.

Comment: @sunkehappy As OP uses incorrect and inconsistent terminology throughout his question, and the root object he has is a view controller, I assume he wants to add a view controller in fact.

Answer (score 0):

While @H2CO3 has provided the very correct answer, I would just like to add that you can also do this with less code, and more structure, provided you like using the Interface Builder. make a segue in IB from ViewController1 to ViewController 2, set it's identifier to something unique, let's say `ToViewController2`. Then your method could look like this:

```
- (void) showAboutPage {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ToViewController2" sender:self];
}
```

Assuming you wanted to pass on some variables as well, you could do this:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ToViewController2"]) {
        [segue destinationViewController setYourVariable:variable];
        // Pass your variables on to the next view here.
    }
}
```

The good thing about this, is that everything that should be passed to the next ViewControllers, assuming you have several segues from that ViewController, is being passed in this method.